# My Diablo 3 account was hacked and my gold and items were stolen. Is there anything I can do to get them back?

Tags: diablo-iii

When I went into my account today all my gold was gone as well as all my undamaged items. Even the items that had been for sale in the auction house were gone. I know that many people are having this issue, but I was wondering is there any way to get the stolen gold and items back?

Comment: have you tried to contact blizzard via a ticket? usually they answer in about ~20 mins...

Comment: This seems like a question suited for Blizzard customer support, not here

Comment: And once you have them back, attach a physical or smartphone authenticator to your account.

Comment: You are not alone, this happened to thousands of other users: http://www.forbes.com/sites/insertcoin/2012/05/30/the-horror-of-being-hacked-in-diablo-3/2/ http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5271603550?page=1

Comment: The forbes article is off based.  The author attempts to place blame upon Blizzard, this isn't a Blizzard problem, its a user security problem.

Answer (score 12):

As per http://us.battle.net/support/en/article/compromised-diablo-iii-account:

> Compromise Restorations in Diablo III will be based on automatically
>   saved restoration points. Restorations will be provided by rolling the
>   entire account back to a restoration point.

In other word, if you contact Blizzard about it, they are going to restore your account to the latest backup they have.

Comment: I should point out. If you want to use the RMAH you will need to get an authenticator. If you get compromised again you will be banned fromt he RMAH because of your inability to keep your account secure.  This policy is outlined in the support article.  I figured I would save people time.

Comment: When an account gets restored, you do not lose achievements because they are account bound even though you will reset items and progress. Also, hackers will not be able to steal any account bound items like Collector's Edition wings or dyes.